# Interpolation in nlp - definition of O term

Tags: nlp, interpolation

Reading definition of interpolation below how are the O terms defined? Is this a value that is set manually?

> ## [Example](https://gist.github.com/ttezel/4138642#example-1)
>
> - P( Sam | I am ) = count( Sam I am ) / count(I am) = 1 / 2
>
> #### Interpolation using N-grams
>
> We can combine knowledge from each of our n-grams by using interpolation.
>
> E.g. assuming we have calculated unigram, bigram, and trigram probabilities, we can do:
>
> P ( Sam | I am ) = Θ<sub>1</sub> x P( Sam ) + Θ<sub>2</sub> x P( Sam | am ) + Θ<sub>3</sub> x P( Sam | I am )

<sub>([original problem statement image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIZUW.jpg))</sub>

Comment: unigram, bigram and trigram probabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Terminology point: those symbols aren't `O`, but thetas `Θ`.

Confusingly, these values labelled theta are normally referred to as lambdas, as in [the page](https://gist.github.com/ttezel/4138642) you quote. They are weights used in interpolation (as opposed to backoff) that sum to 1, and can be calculated from the corpus itself via a variety of methods:

> How are these λ values set? Both the simple interpolation and conditional interpolation λs are learned from a held-out corpus. A held-out corpus is an additional
>   training corpus that we use to set hyperparameters like these λ values, by choosing
>   the λ values that maximize the likelihood of the held-out corpus. That is, we fix
>   the N-gram probabilities and then search for the λ values that when plugged into
>   Eq. [4.24](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf#page=15&zoom=100,0,756) give us the highest probability of the held-out set. There are various ways
>   to find this optimal set of λs. One way is to use the EM algorithm defined in Chapter 7, which is an iterative learning algorithm that converges on locally optimal λs
>   [(Jelinek and Mercer, 1980)](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf#page=27&zoom=100,0,493).
>
> - [*Speech and Language Processing.* Chapter 4: N-Grams](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf) (4.4.3 Backoff and Interpolation) (p.15)

Answer (score 0):

You would treat the thetas like probabilities. So they must be greater than 0 and they must sum to 1. Technically, you set them manually but you can find the optimal values for theta using a variety of methods.